# Max Level Of Inheritance

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, stack-overflow

I've written a source file with 1000 classes all inheriting from the one above:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Class700 class700 = new Class700();            
    }
}
class Class1 { public Class1() { } }
class Class2 : Class1 { public Class2() { } }
class Class3 : Class2 { public Class3() { } }
class Class4 : Class3 { public Class4() { } }
class Class5 : Class4 { public Class5() { } }
//class ClassN : ClassN-1 { public ClassN() { } } where N = 2 to N = 1000
```

I get a StackOverflow exception on `Class700`, however this changes every time I run it, but usually it's around 700.

Can anyone explain why at approximately level 700, a StackOverflow occurs, and why this changes every time I run the program?

I'm using Windows 8.1 Enterprise 64 bit.

Comment: Probably because the constructor calls its base class,and so on. Thus 700 nested function calls exhausts the stack.

Comment: if you have a 700 deep class hierarchy, you have designed it wrong!

Comment: You can increase the stack size of the thread and test it yourself.

Comment: How did you run this? Debug build or Release build? 32 bit or 64 bit? Debugger or no debugger? I would think that, if those conditions are the same, the output would have to be the same as well. Do you see the exception when you run a release build without a debugger? In that case, I would assume (at least some of) those constructor calls are inlined by the jit.

Comment: Try creating another program that recursively calls a function and record how many levels deep you get before a stack overflow exception occurs.

Comment: replace your main function with this `static void Main(string[] args) { Main(args); }` and tell us at which level stack overflow happens. you can optionally add a counter to explicitly see the number of calls.

Comment: Are you creating an instance when it crashes or not?

Comment: Post the exception details.

Comment: @paulm - yes, obviously. But that leaves the question jow 700 calls can exhaust a 1MB stack.

Comment: @MitchWheat - of course, but not on point here.

Comment: Either each call is taking 1497.96 bytes of stack, or something has already used tons of stack before these calls.

Comment: @paulm - the full code is provided. Can you point out either of these?

Comment: @ Henk Holterman: you can cut your toe nails with scythe, but its probably not a good idea.

Comment: I can reproduce this, but only with the debugger enabled. And when you set a breakpoint the problem goes away. So it looks like a bug in the debugger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seeing it bomb at 700 is hard to explain, but we are surely not looking at the real code.  You'd only get something like this in an auto-generated code case, of course nobody would ever write something like this by hand.

But yes, SOE is certainly possible with code like this.  Invisible to the eye, but the constructor of a derived class *always* calls the constructor of its base class.  If you don't write it yourself then the compiler will auto-generate that call.  All the way down to the System.Object constructor.

How much stack space is required for the constructor is something you can see with the debugger.  Just isolate the code for two classes, create a Class2 object and set breakpoints on the Class2 and the Class1 constructors.  You want Debug + Windows + Registers, write down the value of the ESP register, the stack pointer, when the breakpoints hit.  RSP in 64-bit mode.

Doing the same with your code snippet, I get 0x024C012C and 0x024C00E4, a difference of 72 bytes.  Extrapolating that to 700 classes, that would requires 700 x 72 = 50400 bytes.  Not close to SOE, your program bombs when it consumes one megabyte in 32-bit code, 4 megabytes when compiled with a target platform forced to x64.  The jitter has overhead as well, a number you cannot guess at until you subtract the difference.

You can increase the size of the stack with Editbin.exe, /STACK option.  Or create a Thread, use the constructor that lets you set the stack size.

And yes, that it doesn't repeat well is normal.  The CLR implements several anti-malware techniques, one of them is starting the stack at a random location.  That makes it *very* difficult for malware to exploit .NET code with a buffer overflow attack.  Which is a quite unlikely threat to .NET code in general, not a lot of code around that uses `stackalloc`, but the counter-measure is very cheap to implement.